# ui-router not working with material design lite

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to use material-design-lite with ui-router, but my templates are never rendered into the view

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="admin">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
    <base href="/">
    <title ng-bind="state.data.title"></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/material-design-lite/material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="app-layout mdl-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <app-header></app-header>

        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>

        <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100 page">
            <section ui-view></section>
        </main>
    </div>

    <script>
        //Global Variables
    </script>

    <script src="libs/material-design-lite/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/modules/angular-mdl.js"></script>

    <script src="src/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/app.routes.js"></script>

    <script src="src/js/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/controllers/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- Directives -->
    <script src="src/js/directives/header.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js/directives/sidebar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.routers.js file

```
//App Routes
angular.module('admin').
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

        $stateProvider.state('app',{
            abstract: true,
            url: '',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            data: {
                'title': "Admin - Dashboard"
            },
            templateUrl: '/tpls/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        })
    }
]);
```

Comment: Can you set up an error handler and see if any errors are generated?  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#issue-im-getting-a-blank-screen-and-there-are-no-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `template: "<ui-view />"` to your 'app' state's config object

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#abstract-states

> Remember: Abstract states still need their own `<ui-view/>` for their children to plug into. So if you are using an abstract state just to prepend a url, set resolves/data, or run an onEnter/Exit function, then you'll additionally need to set `template: "<ui-view/>"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
  $timeout(function () {
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
  });
});
```

I found that `ui-router` doesn't work well with `material design lite` in my project, And in the source code of `material`, I found an `Window` object `componentHandler`  which has a function `upgradeAllRegistered`, this function should work. So, I called it after `stateChangeSuccess`, and it just worked.

Comment: This answer clearly is worth a little explanation on how it solves the OP issue...

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.